ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter
could you please give a hand to solve pip install jupyterlab gives
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from versions: none)
Python version 3.12 win 64
need to lunch jupyter lab to start Python
